# SQL Query to Return Total Number of Lines and Number of Items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query on two tables that needs to return the total number of lines in each sales order and a total of the items ordered.

A simplified version of the `SalesOrder` table is constructed like this:

| SalesOrderID | Customer | SODate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | Bob Smith | 12/15/2021 |
| 101 | Jane Doe | 12/05/2021 |
| 100 | Sarah Joy | 12/01/2021 |

The second table, `SalesOrderLine`, contains the line items in the sales order:

| SalesOrderID | LineNumber | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | Nuts | 5 |
| 100 | 2 | Bolts | 10 |
| 100 | 3 | Washers | 3 |
| 101 | 1 | Screws | 15 |
| 102 | 1 | Nails | 25 |
| 102 | 2 | Hooks | 5 |

The result of the query would look like this:

| SalesOrderID | SODate | Customer | TotalLines | TotalItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 12/15/2021 | Bob Smith | 2 | 30 |
| 101 | 12/05/2021 | Jane Doe | 1 | 15 |
| 100 | 12/01/2021 | Sarah Joy | 3 | 18 |

I am locking up on how to use the query to return the Total Number of Lines and Total Number of Items per SalesOrderID.

```
SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderID, SalesOrder.SODate, SalesOrder.SOCustomer
```

?? Total Number of Lines and Total Number of Items ??

```
FROM SalesOrder 
INNER JOIN SalesOrders ON SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderLine.SalesOrderID
ORDER BY SalesOrderID
```

Comment: Aren't you just after a `COUNT` and `SUM` here?

Comment: And don't forget `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Well worded question with expected results and what you've tried.  + to Larnu for formatting :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select so.*, soo.*
from salesorder so cross apply
     ( select count(*) as Totallines, sum(soo.quantity) as TotalQty
       from SalesOrders soo
       where soo.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
     ) soo;
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that this is actually conceptually a `LEFT JOIN`, and will return `0` for `SalesOrder` without any matching `SalesOrderLine` if there are any (because it is using [scalar aggregation rather than vector aggregation](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html)). To remove those rows, you can add `GROUP BY ()` inside the apply. To get a `NULL` for those rows you can do the same, but also use `OUTER APPLY`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done, except the aggregation.

**Query**

```
select so.SalesOrderID, so.SODate, so.SOCustomer, 
count(sol.LineNumber) as TotalLines, sum(sol.Quantity) as TotalItems
from SalesOrder as so
join SalesOrderLine as sol
on so.SalesOrderID = sol.SalesOrderID
group by so.SalesOrderID, so.SODate, so.SOCustomer
order by SalesOrderID;
```

Comment: This tip was very helpful in implementation.  Thank you.